# Python listwidget click item button

Tags: button, events, items, qlistwidget

First, you should know I'm very new to Python. I'm currently working on an app to increase my knowledge of this language.

I'm having a QListWidget which contains items based on a widget I created. This widget contains buttons like one to update or another to delete the item.

[image]

So I'm having troubles to do this action. For example, If I click on the update button, I want to open a window and load content by getting the item values.

[image]

How could I do that ?

This is my actual code

MainWindow

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout

from CustomWidgets.fb_line import fb_line
from Data.data_saver import data_saver
from MainWindows import Ui_MainWindow
from Windows.Ajout import Ajout
from Windows.Parametres import Parametres
from Windows.custom_fb_line import custom_fb_line


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.c_fb_l = custom_fb_line()
        self.parametres = Parametres()
        self.ajout = Ajout()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btn_parametre.clicked.connect(self.button_open_parametres)
        self.ui.btn_ajouter.clicked.connect(self.button_open_ajout)
        self.ui.btn_annuler.clicked.connect(self.button_annuler)
        self.ui.btn_fermer.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.addLines()

    def button_open_parametres(self):
        self.parametres.show()

    def button_open_ajout(self):
        self.ajout.show()

    def button_annuler(self):
        self.ui.lw_dossier.clear()
        self.addLines()

    def addLines(self):
        fbs = ds.read_data(data)
        listWidget = self.ui.lw_dossier
        listWidget.reset()

        for fb in fbs:
            item_widget = fb_line(fb)
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(listWidget)
            item.setSizeHint(QSize(0, 50))
            listWidget.addItem(item)
            listWidget.setItemWidget(item, item_widget)

            listWidget.show()


data = "./Data/data.pkl"
ds = data_saver()
```

Widget :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from Objects.enum import enum
from custom_fb_line import Ui_custom_fb_line


class fb_line(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fb, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_custom_fb_line()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.le_source.setText(fb.dossier_source)
        self.ui.le_cible.setText(fb.dossier_cible)
        self.ui.le_cron.setText("tous les " + str(fb.cron.number) + " " + enum().get_types()[fb.cron.type])
        self.ui.btn_delete.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        self.ui.btn_modifier.clicked.connect(self.modifier)
        self.ui.btn_demarrer.clicked.connect(self.demarrer)

    def delete(self):
        print('delete ')

    def modifier(self):
        print('modifier')

    def demarrer(self):
        print('démarrer')
```

So print does actually show in console but I can't figure out how to achieve button click to update or delete items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found a way, which is really simple in fact. Being new to python, I didn't know how to pass arguments to methods plugged to buttons. Here is how to do that for anyone who could have same issues

```
self.ui.btn_delete.clicked.connect(lambda: self.delete(fb))

    def delete(self, fb):
        print('delete ')
        print(fb.dossier_source)
```